# Escape quote in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

I have this grammar :

```
grammar Hello;
STRING : '"' ( ESC | ~[\r\n"])*  '"' ;
fragment ESC : '\\"' ;
r : STRING;
```

I want when i type a string :

```
"my name is : \" StackOverflow \" "
```

the result will be :

```
"my name is : "StackOverflow" "
```

But this is the result when i test it :

[image]

So what should i do to fix it ? Your help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to handle it in your grammar without targeting a specific language. You either strip the slashes when walking your parse tree in a listener or visitor, or embed target specific code in your grammar.

If Java is your target, you could do this:

```
STRING
 : '"' ( ESC | ~[\r\n"] )*  '"'
   {
     String text = getText();
     text = text.substring(1, text.length() - 1);
     text = text.replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1");
     setText(text);
   }
 ;
```